# Which word can honestly portray a non-native's language abilities

Tags: word-choice, learning, non-native-english

I have often been intrigued by the following questions in various documents across the Indian sub-continent:

> Ability to read, speak, and write - Yes.
>
> Fluency level- Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced.

What would be the most appropriate statement (or word) to qualify how well a person speaks a foreign language? It would also have to include the following skills: speaking, listening, reading, and writing.

- I am ***proficient*** in three languages.
- I ***speak*** two languages- one fluently other not so
- I can ***converse*** in two languages
- I ***know*** two languages
- I have ***studied*** three languages
- I have ***learned*** two foreign languages

Comment: The first 3. The rest do not necessarily give an indication of ability

Comment: What do you mean, which would be correct? They all mean entirely different things. I myself know X languages, am fluent in Y, can converse in Z, and have studied exactly zero.

Comment: I think fluent (and its different degrees) is a good adjective to express the concept. Fluency:  the ability to speak easily and smoothly; especially : the ability to speak a foreign language easily and effectively.

Comment: I know -studied, learned etc carry different connotations. As a not so fluent speaker myself, i feel some more inputs would have helped, instead of the 'hold'.

Comment: Qualifying the number of languages you speak is not a bad idea. Statements like, I speak two fluently and am conversational in four others or, I know four and have studied three are good examples of how to honestly portray your language abilities.

Comment: The common, standard levels of studying and knowing a foreign language are, as you mentioned; beginner - intermediate and advanced. You may state that your knowledge or your abilities in a foreign language are at  one of those levels accordingly. I think that would help understand your real knowledge.

Comment: If you do not agree with my edit, you can rollback to the original version, or clarify/improve/change a point. When a question is put on hold, it's not the end, take it as an opportunity to improve and clarify what you are really asking.

Comment: Mari-Lou, post your edit, the question now clearly mirrors what I meant. Thanks to you and must say ELU must be the savior of many non-native speakers!

Comment: @Non-native: We're not supposed to be. That's what [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) is for.

Comment: There is no hard and fast set adjective to express anyone's knowledge.  Fluent means you understand it all, aside from an obscure word. Not fluent can mean you get by with help, to I have no idea what any of the words mean.